# unable to enter for loop in python

Tags: python

Here is my data.csv

```
a,1,1-Jan-2017
a,2,3-Jan-2017
a,4,14-Feb-2017
b,21,1-Dec-2016
b,7,28-Nov-2016
```

My target is to print below as final list. Format is unique(first_column),no.of occurences

```
a,3
b,2
```

Written below python script but unable to enter second block to print 'second block' although the same logic works fine in previous loop.

```
import csv

with open('/home/user/python/data.csv') as csvfile :
    DataCaptured = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    UniqueValues = []
    FinalList = []

    for row in DataCaptured :
            if row[0] not in UniqueValues :
                    UniqueValues.append(row[0])

    print 'Unique values are:\n' + str(UniqueValues)

    for unique in UniqueValues :
            counter = 0
            print 'First block',unique
            for row in DataCaptured :
                    print 'Second block'
                    if unique == row[0] :
                            counter = int(counter)+1
            FinalList.append(unique+','+str(counter))

    print 'Final list:\n' + str(FinalList)
```

Comment: Here is my data.csv

    a,1,1-Jan-2017
    a,2,3-Jan-2017
    a,4,14-Feb-2017
    b,21,1-Dec-2016
    b,7,28-Nov-2016

Comment: `DataCaptured` is a reader object. Not an reusable list. Check documentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the program above a bit and only iterate through the file once:

```
import csv

with open('/home/user/python/data.csv') as csvfile :
    unique_values = {}

    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        element = row[0]
        if element not in unique_values:
            unique_values[element] = 0

        unique_values[element] += 1

    for unique, count in unique_values.items():
        print('{0},{1}'.format(unique, count))
```

Comment: You could also make use of [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 4):

It's because you've already read over the entire file after the first loop; there are no more rows in the reader's iterator at this point. Use `csvfile.seek(0)` after the first `for` loop to return to the beginning of the file, and it will work.